# Why are comparisons wasted in selection sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I am reading about selection sort in the *Algorithms In A Nutshell* book. The following appears in the book:

> Selection sort is slowest of all the sorting algorithms. It
>   repeatedly performs almost the same task without learning anything
>   from one iteration to the next. Selecting the largest element, max,
>   in A takes n-1 comparisons, and selecting the second largest element
>   takes n-1 comparisons - not much progress! **Many of these comparisons
>   are wasted because if an element is smaller than second, it can't
>   possibly be the largest element and therefore had no impact on the
>   computation for the max.**

What does the text in bold mean?

Can someone explain with simple example?

Comment: Take a look at [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) for *the* slowest sorting algorithm.

Comment: There are many much slower sorting algorithms such as bogosort or [stooge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort). Selection sort is just in efficient (the reason was said in the quote), not slowest

Comment: Selection sort can be useful on smaller arrays with a small comparison and a large swap cost.

Answer (score 1):

The author of your book seems to like complicated, long sentences. Don't learn that from him; there are already enough people who know how to confuse their readers.

An attempt to make it more simple to understand:

Selecting the largest element from A takes `n-1` comparisons when A has `n` elements. Unfortunately, the sort algorithm doesn't reuse any of this information.

When it starts the inner loop again to sort the remaining elements, it needs another `n-2` comparisons (one element has been sorted to the right place with the last loop).

Since the sort only moves a single element per run of the inner loop, most of the comparisons are repeated over and over again without doing anything with the result - they are just a waste of time.

Wikipedia has a [nice animation how selection sort works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `3,5,2,4,1`.

The largest element is `5`. The second largest element is `4`.

`3` is smaller than `4`, thus it can't be larger than `5`, thus checking whether it is is essentially a waste.